How can I find many documents by array of key and export them?
Now I want to find document in Mongodb using SQL like follow:
var ids = [1, 2, 3, ...] // about 100000
db.getCollection('table').find({id: {$in: ids})

And then export the found data.
However, the amount of data was so large that no results were found for a long time.

1. Then split your ids into multiple smaller arrays and make multiple calls. 2. Try using use sort, skip & limit. 3. You are using the id field instead the typical _id field, so do you have an index on id? MongoDB automatically creates an index only for _id.
